# Trying to filter a second RollingFile with the first part of a namespace

Tags: serilog

I created a second `RollingFile` for "Information" messages I am keeping track of. However, I am getting all the information messages from my web application, which amount to a lot. I really just want to get the messages for my own modules in this application.

Assuming that I have multiple namespaces that all start with `MyNamespace`, how would I accomplish that in a .json config file? I tried the following to no avail and am sure it's just my own limitations:

```
...
{
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "MyNamespace"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "app_data/logs/nformation-log-{Date}.txt",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff}|{TenantName}|{RequestId}|{SourceContext}|{Level:u3}|{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I do not want to apply this filter to the other log (which is for errors), which is why I tried to nest it within the second `RollingFile`.

Comment: ultimately you have whitelist and blacklist expressions, and you can stack them - that's worked for me in other contexts - is the problem with getting that working or with expressing exactly what to pick/exclude ?

Comment: @RubenBartelink I'm new to Serilog and JSON, so I believe my problem is getting it working. My assumption is that you can nest a Filter within a particular sink, so if that's not the case, and Filters can only be applied globally, then that is my first problem. This is a second `RollingFile` and it works fine, it's just that it has all of my web app's information logs, when I just want to see my own module logs.

Comment: I personally have not used the config system as yet, and would not sink time into understanding RollingFile as its superseded by File - I'd tend to prototype with File and code based config and the drop to json and/or legacy sinks only after getting that working satisfactorily - sorry I can't be directly helpful for you :(